# How to use touch and double click on the image..?

Tags: java, android

I have one imageview, if i touch the imageview it to do some action else if i double click that imageview need to do some action.
How it is possible.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a GestureDetector and a listener. Then bind it to your class that extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.

```
private GestureDetector detector;  
private ImageView mImageView;

@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
  detector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGesturesListener());  
  // TODO find your image view
  mImageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Then you can implement the methods of different gestures:

```
class MyGesturesListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{  
  @Override  
  public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent ev) { 
    // TODO handle single tap 
    return true;  
  }  
  @Override  
  public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent ev) {  
    // TODO handle double tap
    return true;  
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually i have used on single tap for put the image and using touchlistener for moving the image.if i used doubletap on the same image , the image cant move.